# Latest OpenCL Driver for Xeon Phi

Tags: opencl, xeon-phi

I am struggling to get the latest OpenCL driver for Intel Xeon Phi. I have a Knights Corner (KNC) and I only find the deprecated OpenCL Runtime 14.2 (from 2014?). Where can I find the non deprecated release?

Website: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers

If I download the latest Intel OpenCL SDK for Applications, I only get support for the Xeon, but not for the Xeon Phi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unluckily, the latest driver is the 14.2. I got the answer from the Intel forums.

So, it is deprecated, but at the same time is the latest OpenCL driver for the Xeon Phi KNC.